# Junção de um array com um array de objetos

Tags: javascript, json

```
let apis = [{id: "1", name"api 1"}, {id: "2", name:"api 2"}, {id: "3", name:"api 3"}];


let applications = [{id: "1", name:"application 01", apis: ["1", "2"]}, {id: "2", name: "application 02", apis: ["2", "3"]}]
```

Gostaria de um resultado assim:

```
 let resultado = [
{id: "1", name: "application 01", apis: [{id: "1", name:"api 1"}, {id: "2", name:"api 2"}]}, 
{id: "2", name: "application 02", apis: [{id: "2", name:"api 2"}, {id: "3", name:"api 3"}]}]
```

Estou querendo que cada api entre em sua respectiva application. Estou meio confusa nas ideias ainda, estou pensando que vai ter que usar provavelmente um reduce, mas não sei como...
Poderiam me ajudar por favor

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como juntar dois arrays de objetos por chaves diferentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/441261/como-juntar-dois-arrays-de-objetos-por-chaves-diferentes)

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa iterar por todos os elementos de 'applications' e para cada um dele verificar todas as 'apis':

```js
let apis = [{id: "1", name: "api 1"}, {id: "2", name:"api 2"}, {id: "3", name:"api 3"}];
let applications = [{id: "1", name:"application 01", apis: ["1", "2"]}, {id: "2", name: "application 02", apis: ["2", "3"]}];

//pasando por todos os 'applications'
resultado = applications.map(function(app) {
  //cada iteração, aqui dentro, um dos elementos de 'applications' é chamado de 'app'
  //abaixo, filtrando as 'apis' conforme o vetor 'apis' dentro do 'app'
  apisSelecionadas = apis.filter(function(api) {
    //só retorna do 'apis' (principal) os elementos que existam dentro da propriedade 'apis' do 'app' 
    return app.apis.indexOf(api.id) !== -1;
  });
  //coloco o resultado no 'app'
  app.apis = apisSelecionadas;

  return app;
});

console.log(resultado)
```

Comment: tem referencia circular no objeto

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção seria iterar sobre cada elemento de `applications` e, para cada iteração, procurar, no array `apis`, o objeto `api` correspondente:

```js
function groupApplicationApi(applications, apis) {
  // Cria um novo array para não modificar o original:
  const resultingArray = [];

  for (const application of applications) {
    // Também criamos um novo objeto para não modificar o original:
    const applicationObj = { ...application };
    const apiObjs = [];

    for (const apiId of applicationObj.apis) {
      const apiObj = apis.find((api) => api.id === apiId);

      // Se não existir API correspondente, não faça nada:
      if (!apiObj) {
        continue;
      }

      apiObjs.push(apiObj);
    }

    // Adiciona as apis ao novo objeto:
    applicationObj.apis = apiObjs;

    // Adiciona o novo objeto no array resultante:
    resultingArray.push(applicationObj);
  }

  return resultingArray;
}

const apis = [
  { id: '1', name: 'api 1' },
  { id: '2', name: 'api 2' },
  { id: '3', name: 'api 3' }
];

const applications = [
  { id: '1', name: 'application 01', apis: ['1', '2'] },
  { id: '2', name: 'application 02', apis: ['2', '3'] }
];

console.log(
  groupApplicationApi(applications, apis)
);
```

Mas, de modo geral, o algoritmo acima não é muito performático, uma vez que, para cada elemento de `applications`, iteraremos (no pior dos cenários) sobre cada elemento de `apis`.

Desse modo, a [**complexidade**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56836/69296) é `O(m * n)`, sendo `m` o número de elementos de `applications` e `n` o número de elementos de `apis`.

Dá para fazer em `O(m + n)`, o que é indubitavelmente melhor — apesar de causar leve custo em memória, uma vez que teremos que manter um dicionário com cada elemento de `apis` disponível, indexada pelo respectivo ID.

Enfim, assim:

```js
function groupApplicationApi(applications, apis) {
  const apiDict = Object.create(null); // Cria o dicionário:
  for (const api of apis) {
    apiDict[api.id] = api;
  }

  const resultingArray = [];
  for (const application of applications) {
    const applicationObj = { ...application };
    
    const apiObjs = [];
    for (const apiId of applicationObj.apis) {
      // Note que não utilizamos o `find` (O(n)), apenas uma indexação (O(1)).
      const apiObj = apiDict[apiId];

      if (!apiObj) {
        continue;
      }

      apiObjs.push(apiObj);
    }

    applicationObj.apis = apiObjs;
    resultingArray.push(applicationObj);
  }

  return resultingArray;
}

const apis = [
  { id: '1', name: 'api 1' },
  { id: '2', name: 'api 2' },
  { id: '3', name: 'api 3' }
];

const applications = [
  { id: '1', name: 'application 01', apis: ['1', '2'] },
  { id: '2', name: 'application 02', apis: ['2', '3'] }
];

console.log(
  groupApplicationApi(applications, apis)
);
```

---

<sup>Note que, nos dois exemplos acima, evitei tentar modificar os elementos originais. Sempre que uma modificação foi necessária no código, foi feita em uma "cópia", e não no original. No entanto, as referências aos objetos de `apis` foram mantidas.</sup>

Comment: tem referencia circular no objeto

Comment: Como, @RicardoPontual - poderia tentar detalhar mais? Referência circular me parece impossível no código acima.

Comment: se executar o snippet vai ver que aparece  "/**ref:5**/,"

Comment: E o que isso tem a ver com referência circular? Até onde sei, parece-me apenas uma referência a um objeto - não uma referência circular.

Comment: escrevi referencia, é dependência circular sorry :)  isso é o mesmo que "[circular object Object]"

Comment: Ok, permita-me perguntar – onde você quer chegar com isso? Tem algum problema?

Comment: exatamente o que comentei, só ilustrar que existe dependência circular no código, ai cabe a quem usar o exemplo pensar se faz diferença ou não

Comment: @RicardoPontual, eu acho errado usar o termo "circular". Não tem nada de circular (não tem [dependência circular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) e nem [referência circular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference)!) no código acima. Ainda acho que você quer dizer "referência" (o que de fato acontece).

Comment: tbm acho que o termo não é o melhor, inclusive eu mesmo ainda errei ao escrever "dependencia circular" como "referência circular", mas é assim que é chamado, acho que por falta de outro, pq o termo "dependencia circular" é mais usado no conceito de pacotes

Comment: @RicardoPontual, não, realmente não é nenhum desses dois termos, porque, como disse, não tem nada de circular em nenhum dos códigos desta pergunta. O que está acontecendo é a manutenção de uma simples **referência**. O termo é, portanto, "referência" - e só. Tem que tomar cuidado para não confundir...

Comment: @RicardoPontual Esse `/**ref:5**/` é simplesmente para indicar que o objeto que está ali é o mesmo que está anteriormente em outro ponto (no caso, mais acima, onde tem `/**id:5**/`). Mas isso não é necessariamente circular, pois a mesma referência para o mesmo objeto pode estar em vários lugares e não dar problema nenhum. Seria circular se o objeto A tem uma referência para B, que por sua vez tem uma referência para A (uma forma de saber se dá problema é tentar converter para JSON). Veja aqui um exemplo: https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/CircularReferences#index.js

Comment: coloquei uma resposta para tentar exemplificar melhor, eu entendo que o termo "soa estranho", mas quero só dizer que, ao fazer isso, temos uma referência para o mesmo objeto, era só e apenas isso desde o início

Comment: Não é "soar estranho", é um termo errado, @RicardoPontual. É a mesma coisa de chamar uma batata de beterraba. É, de certo modo, parecido, mas está errado. Não há referência circular aqui.

Comment: bom @LuizFelipe não vou discutir a nomenclatura contigo, como falei está até nos links do SO, se não concordas pode comentar lá, eu só estou usando o que tem lá e na internet, de novo, não sou eu quem baizo as coisas :)

Comment: O link do SO está certo, você só o referenciou em um contexto incorreto.

Comment: @RicardoPontual "*temos uma referência para o mesmo objeto*" - sim, mas a pergunta não deixa claro se era pra ser uma cópia do objeto ou o mesmo. _Talvez_ valha a pena alertar que por causa disso, uma alteração no objeto também afeta o resultado (como vc fez). Mas no caso desta resposta, a referência **não é circular**. Circular é quando um objeto A aponta para B e B aponta para A. Aqui temos um array com 2 elementos diferentes apontando para o mesmo objeto (ou seja, temos A e B apontando para C, não há o "círculo se fechando"). É só a mesma referência usada em vários lugares, ponto :-)

Comment: E só para constar que eu deixei uma observação no final da minha resposta para chamar a atenção do leitor sobre as cópias que foram (e talvez precisem ser) feitas. cc: @RicardoPontual

Comment: obrigado @LuizFelipe, e de novo, de forma alguma é alguma critica a qualquer das respostas, eu mesmo ia começar a redigir uma resposta, mas já tinham respondido as ideias que eu tinha, era só para comentar da referência em si, talvez o objeto gerado vai ser só para leitura, e isso tudo nem vai importar

Comment: Eu entendo, @RicardoPontual. O maior problema que eu enxergo nos comentários mesmo é que foi utilizado um termo incorreto (o que decerto pode causar alguma confusão). Recapitulando isso, fica tudo certo. =)

Answer (score 3):

Outra alternativa seria indexar cada elemento do array `apis` pelo seu `id` e usar cada valor de `applications.apis` como chave nesse índice.

```js
let apis = [
  {id: "1", name: "api 1"}, 
  {id: "2", name: "api 2"}, 
  {id: "3", name: "api 3"}
];

let applications = [
  {id: "1", name: "application 01", apis: ["1", "2"]}, 
  {id: "2", name: "application 02", apis: ["2", "3"]}
];
   
let index = [];
let result = [];

//Indexa cada elemento de apis pelo seu id.
for(let e of apis){
  index[e.id] = e;  
  //index[e.id] = {...e};  //caso queira criar um objeto novo ao invés de referenciar os objetos já existentes use essa linha. 
}

//Para cada elemento de applications...
for(let e of applications){
  let apis=[]                          //...inicializa a lista que receberá as substituições para esse elemento.
  //...para cada um dos valores em e.apis...
  for(let v of e.apis){
    apis.push(index[v])                //...obtém o elemento indexado pelo valor e salva em apis.
  }
  //Monta o resultado.
  result.push({"id":e["id"],"name":e["name"],"apis":apis})
}

for(var e of result){console.log(e)}
```

O mesmo código acima em versão funcional.

```js
let apis = [
  {id: "1", name: "api 1"}, 
  {id: "2", name: "api 2"}, 
  {id: "3", name: "api 3"}
];

let applications = [
  {id: "1", name: "application 01", apis: ["1", "2"]}, 
  {id: "2", name: "application 02", apis: ["2", "3"]}
];

let index = apis.reduce((r,e)=>{
  r[e.id]= e;
  //r[e.id] = {...e};  //caso queira criar um objeto novo ao invés de referenciar os objetos já existentes use essa linha.
  return r;
},[]);

let result = applications.reduce((r,e)=>{
  let apis= e.apis.reduce((r,e)=>{
    r.push(index[e]);
    return r
  },[]);   
  r.push({"id":e["id"],"name":e["name"],"apis":apis})
  return r
},[]);    

for(var e of result){console.log(e)}
```

Comment: E se os IDs forem espaçados? Aí o _array_ vai ficar [esburacado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF6sI.png)? :P Eu me sempre esqueço dessa técnica de usar o array (que sempre me deixa surpreso porque é muito interessante), mas, nesse caso, não seria melhor utilizar os _índices_ (índice mesmo) de cada elemento do array `apis`?

Comment: @LuizFelipe O array de índice fica esburacado mesmo. Para falar a verdade ele já começa esburacado, o índice 0 é o primeiro buraco.

Comment: `console.log(index)` vai retornar algo assim(estou fazendo de cabeça perdoe as falhas): `[undefined, {id: "1", name: "api 1"}, {id: "2", name: "api 2"}, {id: "3", name: "api 3"}]`

Comment: Sim - ao utilizar o `id`, na prática, é a mesma coisa que utilizar um objeto. :-)

Comment: Eu entendi o seu ponto @LuizFelipe, mas eu faço isso pensando que o array `apis` pode não estar com as entradas ordenadas, ex: `let apis = [{id: "3", name: "api 3"},{id: "1", name: "api 1"},{id: "2", name: "api 2"}];`

Comment: tem referencia circular no objeto

Comment: @RicardoPontual não há referência circular. O que ocorre é que ao fazer `console.log(result)`  browser cria uma arvore de referências para os objetos aninhados e imprime a primeira ocorrência e apenas marca onde seriam inseridas as repetições. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#logging_objects

Comment: @AugustoVasques vc usou o JSON serializer que "mascara" isso. Faça o seguinte, antes da linha que serializa o código coloque isso `result[0].apis[1].name = "bananas";` e veja como fica o objeto. Edite a pergunta e acrescente isso pf

Comment: @RicardoPontual, isso **não** significa referência circular. As referências são _as mesmas_ e, por causa disso, esse é um comportamento esperado (e, novamente, não se trata de comportamento circular).

Comment: Mesmo assim o AP está pedindo *Estou querendo que cada api entre em sua respectiva application.* se criar um objeto novo `r[e.id]= {...e}` ela perde as referências do original.

Comment: gente, de novo **não sou eu quem dou nome as coisas**, só é assim que são chamadas as depencencia ciclicas, tem vários textos sobre isso por exemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962018/detecting-and-fixing-circular-references-in-javascript, e esse https://dev.to/salyadav/deep-clone-of-js-objects-with-circular-dependency-4if7   só quero alertar que, ao setar uma referencia do objeto para ele mesmo num objeto nested vai ter uma referencia circular, mas tratem como quiserem o tema, não é crítica as respostas, acho q todos entenderam mal

Comment: Você está entendendo errado. Referências circulares realmente existem, mas (repito) não é isso que está acontecendo aqui...

Comment: Não há dependência cíclica. Faça o seguinte `for(var e of result){console.log(e)}` e veja por si. Se fizer isso `JSON.stringify(result)` em um objeto com referencia cíclica o programa trava.

Comment: @LuizFelipe leia os links, se acha que está errado comente lá, de novo, só estou comentando para um detalhe, e é assim que vejo sendo chamado, se é ou não aqui não é o melhor fórum para discutir a nomenclatura

Comment: Não está errado lá. Na pergunta que você linkou realmente há dependência círcular. Só que isso **não acontece aqui**. Você está estipulando ligações e termos desconexos e que não acontecem aqui. Leia os links referidos em [meu outro comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/496269/jun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-um-array-com-um-array-de-objetos/496291?noredirect=1#comment921336_496277) para entender o que é uma dependência circular e referência circular.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, se colocar a linha de código que falei, vai ver que altera os dois objetos, pq eles tem a mesma referência. Numa linguagem como `C#` isso é claro como a água, pois é uma referência de objetos, no javascript infelizmente tem esse nome, de novo eu só apontei náo dei nome as coisas :)

Comment: O que AP que pediu. Novamente isso `JSON.stringify(result)` em um objeto com referência cíclica dá o erro `"TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"`

Comment: coloquei numa resposta para tentar exemplificar melhor

Answer (score 2):

Devido aos inúmeros comentários, para tentar explicar melhor vou redigir uma resposta, se acharem que ajuda fica aqui, senão podemos remover.

Vou pegar por exemplo o código da resposta do @AugustoVasques:

```js
let apis = [
  {id: "1", name: "api 1"}, 
  {id: "2", name: "api 2"}, 
  {id: "3", name: "api 3"}
];

let applications = [
  {id: "1", name: "application 01", apis: ["1", "2"]}, 
  {id: "2", name: "application 02", apis: ["2", "3"]}
];
   
let index = [];
let result = [];

//Indexa cada elemento de apis pelo seu id.
for(let e of apis){
  index[e.id] = e;
}

//Para cada elemento de applications...
for(let e of applications){
  let apis=[]                          //...inicializa a lista que receberá as substituições para esse elemento.
  //...para cada um dos valores em e.apis...
  for(let v of e.apis){
    apis.push(index[v])                //...obtém o elemento indexado pelo valor e salva em apis.
  }
  //Monta o resultado.
  result.push({"id":e["id"],"name":e["name"],"apis":apis})
}

// Aqui, vai apontar a tal "dependencia circular" com /**id:5**/
console.log(result);
/*
Isso indica que, um mesmo objeto tem referência ao mesmo objeto "filho" (nesse caso, "apis") em pontos diferentes. Isso é demonstrado alterando esse objeto com a mesma referência.
Veja que será alterado um elemento, mas ao serializar, TODAS as referências são alteradas.
*/

console.log("Agora vai ser alterado um único objeto:");

result[0].apis[1].name = "bananas";

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)))
```

Vejam que, ao alterar um único objeto, todos que tem a mesma referência são alterados. Isso numa linguagem com `C#` é algo claro de entender, porque objetos tem refências para outros.

Como o @Luiz Felipe comentou, é um nome que não cabe muito bem para isso, mas é assim que tenho lido e é assim que é chamado, por exemplo nesses links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962018/detecting-and-fixing-circular-references-in-javascript

https://dev.to/salyadav/deep-clone-of-js-objects-with-circular-dependency-4if7

Eu só comentei para alertar para um fato comum e que tem várias perguntas inclusive aqui no SOPt sobre alterar objetos com mesma referência, por exemplo:

```
var obj1 = new AlgumaClasse();
obj1.Nome = "Batatas";
obj2 = obj1;
obj2.Nome = "Bananas";

// logo, por referência, obj1.Nome também será igual a "Bananas"
```

Comment: É justamente essa possibilidade de propagar a alteração em um hotspot que AP procura. Se ele tiver que mudar algum valor on fly ele não precisará procurar quais objetos deverá mudar, apenas altera o valor em `apis`.

Comment: Por exemplo a api aponta para `https://minhaapi/func/123?format=json` e durante o funcionamento do programa o servidor `minhaapi` sai do ar e e o AP tem que mudar para `mirrorminhaapi` então só troca a respectiva entrada no array `api` para `https://mirrorminhaapi/func/123?format=json` e alteração é propagada.

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi o problema de manter as referências. Claro, quando se quer evitar mutações, copia-se o valor (como eu fiz na minha resposta quando precisei de modificar algum valor - linhas 3 e 7). No entanto, os objetos de `apis` não não modificados, então não tem porque copiá-los, uma vez que implicaria em custo de memória adicional desnecessário. Esse comportamento de referências é comum e esperado no JavaScript e é algo que o programador deve se atentar ao trabalhar com objetos (que são passados por referência).

Comment: Não vejo problema @LuizFelipe, desde que isso fique claro. O exemplo de código que coloquei na resposta, pode ser um problema para uma pessoa, mas para outra não, pode se exatamente o que ela precisa, mas é importante deixar claro. No exemplo da pergunta, pegamos dois objetos que nada tem de referencia um com outro e geramos um novo novo com referências, é importante mostrar. Se vai fazer diferença ou não, depende de quem vai usar

Comment: @AugustoVasques acho que entendi seu ponto, foi até longe nesse exemplo kkk mas acho que se isso fosse um exemplo de Java ou C# por exemplo eu provavelmente escreveria "esse exemplo gera uma referencia by objeto", e tudo seria mais claro, o problema que o termpo "dependencia circular" gerou muita dúvida

Comment: @RicardoPontual, por exemplo se não quiser indexar as referências e criar um novo objeto para cada entrada na linha onde está `index[e.id] =e;` troque `index[e.id] = {...e};` que o programa vai se comportar diferente, e alteração `apis[0].name= "banana";` não surte mais efeito. Toma um +1 para não zerar pois é ponto de vista válido.

Comment: pra mim deu o mesmo resultado @AugustoVasques :(

Comment: Não use o `console.log(result);` ele vai tentar otimizar e ao invés de mandar a referncia para o objeto ele vai mandar a referencia para a string, use `for(var e of result){console.log(e)}`

Comment: Veja o exemplo: https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/WiseWastefulSet#index.js

Comment: wow interessante, esse link roda `nojejs`? eu testei na pergunta e ficou igual, coloquei aqui tbm e ficou a mesma coisa: https://jsfiddle.net/dry251xc/

Comment: Mas você mudou direto no resultado `result[0].apis[1].name = "bananas";` em `result[0]` a saída será bananas, mude na origem: `apis[0].name= "banana";`. Sim é Node.

Comment: exato @AugustoVasques, senão não se consegue validar a referência :) veja que se usar `result[0].apis[0].name` que não tem referência funciona. O que importa é o resultado final depois do mapping

Comment: No caso se quiser impedir que o resultado do mapeamento, depois de obtido, seja posteriormente alterado esse pode ser congelado com [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o array map, para mapear seu objeto conforme o modelo que deseja apresentar:

```
let apis = [
  {id: "1", name: "api 1"}, 
  {id: "2", name: "api 2"}, 
  {id: "3", name: "api 3"}
];

let applications = [
  {id: "1", name: "application 01", apis: ["1", "2"]}, 
  {id: "2", name: "application 02", apis: ["2", "3"]}
];

var collection = [];

 collection[0] = apis.map((val) => {
  return {
     id:val.id,
     name:val.name,
     apis:(val.apis) ? val.apis : []
  }
});

collection[1] = applications.map((val) => {
  return {
     id:val.id,
     name:val.name,
     apis:val.apis
  }
});

console.log(collection)
```